# within a hairbreadth of something

Tags: comprehension

Example:

> The digital camcorder is not your father's 8mm movie camera. Fifty years ago, family events and
>   vacations were recorded on narrow silent film that faded with the years and grew jerkier each
>   time it was fed through the home projector. Today, the family video camera comes within **a hairbreadth of producing movies**-videos that are technically as good as you see in the theaters or on
>   a TV set. For all the similarities between digital video and still cameras, they are, for the time
>   being, different animals. Because the subjects in videos are constantly moving, the eye doesn't
>   notice if the image is not as sharp as a good photo. But the two animals are evolving into a new
>   creature-one joins the different circuitry and mechanisms needed to shoot both stills and motion.

I don't know how I should understand that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of two expressions:

*To come within [a distance] of [something]*, which means just what it sounds like: to get very close, whether literally or metaphorically.

and

*a hairbreadth* or *hair's breadth*, the width of a [human] hair, which is used to mean a practically infinitesimal distance.

Answer (score 3):

The term you are looking for is *within a hairbreadth of <something>*, a figurative way of saying *very close*.

A hair is very thin, it's width is very, very narrow. So if something comes *within a hairbreadth* it comes very close.

In this example, it is claimed that there is very little difference between the video quality achieved by home video cameras and professional cameras for cinema or TV productions.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" form is [*within a **hair's breadth***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=within%20a%20hairbreadth%2Cwithin%20a%20hairsbreadth%2Cwithin%20a%20hairs%20breadth%2Cwithin%20a%20hair%27s%20breadth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwithin%20a%20hairbreadth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithin%20a%20hairsbreadth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithin%20a%20hairs%20breadth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithin%20a%20hair%20%27s%20breadth%3B%2Cc0), as the NGram in that link demonstrates.

Google Books claims 1090 written instances of [*within a hair's breadth*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22within%20a%20hairbreadth%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22within%20a%20hair%27s%20breadth%22), plus another 171 for [*within a hairs breadth*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22within%20a%20hairbreadth%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22within%20a%20hairs%20breadth%22) and 474 for [*within a hairsbreadth*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22within%20a%20hairbreadth%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22within%20a%20hairsbreadth%22). Those are all indistinguishable in *speech*, and they far outnumber 203 hits for [*within a hairbreadth*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22within%20a%20hairbreadth%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#) (which ***sounds*** somewhat "dialectal" to me).

But Google Books isn't too good with this type of search term - if I search for [*within a hair breadth*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22within%20a%20hairbreadth%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22within%20a%20hair%20breadth%22) it asks if I meant ***hair's breadth*** (all the results on at least the first couple of pages are for that form).

So my advice would be if you don't *yet* know the idiom, learn it as including the /s/ sound when you say it, regardless of how you present it in the written form.

An extremely similar and very closely related idiomatic usage is *came within a **whisker*** (came very close to doing something, used in relation to both good and bad actions/outcomes).